# Gmail auth has higher authority over Facebook auth - Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have "One account per email address" set in my Firebase console and have implemented gmail and facebook authentication in my app.

In the scenario where a facebook account uses the same email as a gmail account here's what happens:

If I authenticate with gmail then later sign out and authenticate with facbeook (which uses the same email as the gmail), I'll get the error:

> errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse

However, if I authenticate with facebook first then authenticate with gmail, then no error is thrown and the user's entry in the Firebase authentication console gets overwritten.

What gives?

Comment: It's slightly different: Google sing-in is the preferred provider for @gmail.com addresses, since it can guarantee their authenticity. Signing in with Google with a gmail that has previously been used for a different provider will indeed reset the previous account for that address. I'm pretty sure that has been asked before, so I'll find a dupe.

Comment: ah... well thats an interesting feature